# how to bypass paypal checkout and send simplecart details through email in javamail using servlet?

Tags: java, shopping-cart, simplecart

I have implemented simpleCart in my project.

I want such a solution that, whenever I click on checkout, instead of going to paypal the simpleCart contents should be sent to a servlet where the servlet sends it as an email using javamail class in java

I googled this query but the solution I found was for PHP and I am not familiar with PHP.

Anyone knowing how to do it using java please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with Java, but you can edit the checkout method in simplecart. For example you can send a form:

```
simpleCart({
    checkout: {
        type: "SendForm" ,
        url: "http://example.com/your/custom/checkout/url" ,
        method: "GET" ,
        success: "success.html" ,
        cancel: "cancel.html" ,
        extra_data: {
            customInfo1: "some custom information",
            customInfo2: "12321321"
        }
    }
});
```

And with that you can handle the data in your custom servlet. For further Information read the simplecart [docs](http://simplecartjs.org/documentation).